# PHP inconsistent date formats and outputs, date_create vs date, etc

Tags: php

Please can somebody help me to understand the difference between the 2 ways of creating a date and the 2 echo commands below? I learning PHP and having a lot of trouble making a TV guide due to inconsistency between similar date commands.

On the "if", it will only echo $guideStartDate if I use that full line with the format options.

On the "else", it will only echo $guideStartDate if I use that basic line.

The documentation is very poor on the PHP manual and this has taken many hours of my time getting to work!

If a user clicks a time on the TV Guide, the guide starts from that time. Else it defaults to now (current time).

```
   if (!empty($_GET['timespec'])) {
    $t1 = $_GET['timespec'];
    $in = date_create();
    $guideStartDate = date_create($in->format("Y-m-d $t1:00:00"));
    echo $guideStartDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    else 
    {
    $guideStartDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    echo $guideStartDate;
    }
```

Comment: you would probably be much happier using Carbon for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
$guideStartDate = new DateTime();
if (!empty($_GET['timespec'])) {
    $t1 = $_GET['timespec'];
    echo $guideStartDate->format("Y-m-d $t1:00:00");
    }
    else 
    {
    echo $guideStartDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
```

Comment: Woohoo! It works! Thank you so much! :D
Although I don't understand why the 2 echo commands gave different results, but that doesn't matter now! Many hours more headache have been avoided. Regards